# Finding the next closest number in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a list:

```
lst = [100, 210, 330, 460, 600, 750, 910, 1080, 1260]
```

and a given number `470`

I want to find the next upper bound of the interval between its two closest numbers...
This would give `600` because it is the next closest number.

If it were `670` I would get `750`.

I have `lst[min(range(len(lst)), key = lambda i: abs(lst[i]-K))]` which is giving the closet number regardless if it is the upper bound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) which gives you the left most insertion index (given the list is sorted which your post seems to indicate it is) in logarithmic time:

```
from bisect import bisect_left

A[bisect_left(A, 460)]
460
>>> A[bisect_left(A, 470)]
600
>>> A[bisect_left(A, 670)]
750
```

This will raise an `IndexError` for numbers greater than `1260`.

Comment: If the number itself is excluded from this search, as *next upper bound* would suggest, then bisect_right would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, it is not entirely clear for that case. I will leave it as is with your comment.

Answer (score 2):

```py
filter(lambda x: x>=460, A).__next__() # 460
filter(lambda x: x>=470, A).__next__() # 600
filter(lambda x: x>=670, A).__next__() # 750
```

Comment: Instead of `list(...)[0]`, just use `next(...)` ;-) That will save space and spurious iterations

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks

Comment: Ooh, don't use the dunder methods like that. That's what's called under the hood. `next(filter(...))` is the way to go. If you ask me though, filter + lambda is a crime in itself :P `next(x for x in A if x >= 460)` is shorter and more readable.

Comment: @schwobaseggl can you give me blog links or other links that explain why filter+lambda is bad? I'm still learning python

Comment: schwobaseggl meant to use `next` as `next(filter(lambda x: x>=460, A))`, instead of  `__next__()`

Comment: https://treyhunner.com/2018/09/stop-writing-lambda-expressions/#Overuse:_lambda_with_map_and_filter can get you started. Other than that it is certainly a matter of taste. I use `map/filter` when there is an available named function to use, otherwise a conditional genrator seems more Pythonic and is shorter to write.